# Why is there an additional empty element in the array after splitting a string using regex in Perl?

Tags: arrays, regex, string, perl, split

In the code below, what is the reason behind $tmp[0] being empty?

```
my $ver = "Q050";
my @tmp = ();

if ($ver =~ /Q0\d\d/) {
    @tmp = split(/Q0/, $ver);
}
print("tmp: @tmp\n");
print("tmp[0] = $tmp[0]\n");
print("tmp[1] = $tmp[1]\n");
```

Output -

```
tmp:  50
tmp[0] =
tmp[1] = 50
```

Am i missing something here?
Thanks.

Comment: Since the match occurs at the start of the string, `split` returns the emty string at the string start as a separate element. See [Perl split with empty text before/after delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3711709/3832970).

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor. I had a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3711709/3832970 but didn't quite understand. Any suggestion as to what i can modify in my code so that i get only one element? Thanks.

Comment: I would not use `split` here. Use "normal" matching with `/Q0(\d\d)/`.

Comment: You could also assign to a list rather than an array if you always have this kind of input, and explicitly throw one away. `(undef, my $num) = split /Q0/, $ver;`

Comment: `split` isn't the right tool. `my ($follows) = $ver =~ /Q0(\d\d.*)/s;`